# Is calling the method I'm testing in a before block bad practice?

Tags: testing, rspec

> ```
> # the first
> it "should render China's jobs page with country_name china" do
>   get 'show', country: 'china'
>   expect(assigns(:title)).to eq("#{location.country} Tech Jobs")
>   expect(response).to be_success
> end
>
> # the second
> context "with country name" do
>   before { get 'show', country: 'china' }
>   it { expect(assigns(:title)).to eq("#{location.country} Tech Jobs") }
>   it { expect(response).to be_success }
> end
> ```

Which one do you think is better?
I prefer the second one if `before { get 'show' }` is not a bad practice.

Comment: http://betterspecs.org/

Comment: I use the first form because, unlike the second, it expresses the requirement that's being tested.

Comment: Although I think this kind of thing is important (even more so than some objective minutia) it is probably not objective enough for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a bad practice, but it does have some downsides:

- It's slower. In the second case, it's got 2 examples, each of which runs `get 'show', country: 'china'` -- which can cause noticeable slowness when `get 'show'` is itself slow.
- It produces documentation output that (to me at least) doesn't really describe the behavior very well.  Compare the `--format doc` output for the two cases.
- It makes it harder to add extra setup to additional examples you may add in the future.  Consider if there's a future case you need to test that needs particular records inserted in the DB to work properly.  Because the action being tested (`get 'show')` is in a `before` block rather than in the example body, you can't easily add additional setup to one example that needs it.  (You can, of course, add that additional setup to the `before` block itself, but that will exacerbate the slowness issue).

There are also some benefits to using the `before` block. It makes it easy to follow the "one expectation per example" guideline. This in turn will give you separate failing or passing examples for the `assigns` and the response status expectations, which can make it more clear what precisely is failing, for example.

Which you use depends on what tradeoffs you want to make.  I personally tend towards your first example (no `before` block).

On a side note, if I was to use the latter form, I'd use the `specify` alias (rather than `it`) because I like to only use `it` when the doc string or matcher reads well as an english expression off of `it`:

```
specify { expect(assigns(:title)).to eq("#{location.country} Tech Jobs") }
specify { expect(response).to be_success }
```